# Pure GWT, events converting

Tags: java, events, gwt, flextable

So, I have a ‘FlexTable’ in GWT and I need to drop down list of actions on right click on some cell. On left mouse click to retrieve ‘rowIndex’ of my cell I simply use ClickEvent method ‘getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex()’. But there is no right click handler in pure GWT. So I decided to use ContextMenuHandler which requires ContextMenuEvent. And, of course, I can’t put ContextMenuEvent into ClickEvent method ‘getCellForEvent’. Is there any solution to this case? Or maybe someone knows easier way to drop down list on rightClick on ‘FlexTable’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a CellTable or DataGrid Widget, you can handle the `CellPreviewEvent` that gets fired when a cell is clicked, and that can also tell you which row/cell the event happened in.  Here is some code:

```
private void makeItemRightClickListener()
{
    grid.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<T> event)
        {
            if (event.getNativeEvent().getButton() !=
                        NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT)
                return;

            // Prevent browser's own context menu from appearing
            event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
            event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();

            handleItemRightClickEvent(event);
        }
    });
}

private void handleItemRightClickEvent(CellPreviewEvent<T> event)
{
    NativeEvent nativeClickEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
    // Get the data (type T) that is being displayed in the cell
    // by the CellTable or DataGrid widget.
    T rowClicked = event.getValue();

    // Create PopupPanel for menu
    PopupPanel popup = ...

    // Show the popup menu at the click position
    UIObject target = new MousePointUIObject(nativelickEvent);
    popup.showRelativeTo(target);
}

private static class MousePointUIObject extends UIObject
{
    private NativeEvent mouseEvent;

    public MousePointUIObject(NativeEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        this.mouseEvent = mouseEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAbsoluteLeft()
    {
        return mouseEvent.getClientX() + Window.getScrollLeft();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAbsoluteTop()
    {
        return mouseEvent.getClientY() + Window.getScrollTop();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOffsetWidth()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOffsetHeight()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for a CellTable or DataGrid widget, but not FlexTable.  With the former I applied one handler object to the entire grid widget and used the event to work out the row or cell that the event happened in.  I can't see how that can be done with FlexTable.

With FlexTable, a hack would be to create a handler object for each cell, and tell it the cell/row at the time of creation.  Something like this:

```
    cell.addDomHandler(new ContextMenuHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event)
        {
            // stop the browser from opening the context menu
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            NativeEvent nativeClickEvent = event.getNativeEvent();

            displayPopupMenuForCell(cell, nativeClickEvent);
        }
    }, ContextMenuEvent.getType());
```

In the above, `cell` needs to be a Widget.  So you would need to get the  Element in the HTMLTable (FlexTable exends HTMLTable which is a normal HTML table element) and wrap it as a Widget.  I am not sure how to do that, but it would be possible.

One other thing, you need to prevent the browser from popping up its own context menu.  I added this to the html file in the `body` tag:

```
  <body oncontextmenu="return false" >
```

Comment: One thing, I’d like to see through displayPopupMenuForCell method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Huge_Noob Refer to my other answer on how to display the popup, for a CellTable or DataGrid

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use click handler to check what button was clicked, left, right or middle what you need to do is something like this :

```java
Button button= new Button();
button.addClickHandler(event -> {
    NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
    if(NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT == nativeEvent.getButton()){
        event.stopPropagation();
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: is he using buttons?  He is using a flex table and wants to ID the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I gave up trying this thing with FlexTable and moved to CellTable, that seems easier.